# Ex dividend date once or multiple times a year for a given stock?

Tags: dividends, ex-dividend-date

Could anyone please clarify a confusion for me ? I am fairly new to stock investing and more specifically to dividend investing. I understand dividend dates (declaration, ex-dividend, report, payment) and the implications of each. What’s not clear to me is if there is only one ex-dividend date per year for a given stock or if there is one every trimester ?

For example, Let’s say Coca Cola stock ex-dividend date was August 1st 2020 and I decide to purchase it now (August 28th), does that mean I will not benefit from any dividend payments until after the August 2021 ex-dividend date one year from now ?

Or is there an opportunity to receive dividend payments throughout the year ?

I cannot tell if there are multiple ex-dividend dates throughout the year or just one.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Trimester gotta be pretty rate. I don't know of any stock paying dividends 3 times a year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What’s not clear to me is if there is only one ex-dividend date per year for a given stock or if there is one every trimester ?

There's one ex-dividend date for each *dividend payment*. Typically that's quarterly, but occasionally companies will pay in other frequencies or irregular "special dividends" in unusual circumstances.

> Let’s say Coca Cola stock ex-dividend date was August 1st 2020 and I decide to purchase it now (August 28th), does that mean I will not benefit from any dividend payments until after the August 2021 ex-dividend date one year from now ?

No, it means that you do not get the dividend that was paid in early August. If you own the stock on the *next* ex-div date, you will be entitled to the dividend.

Since you are new to stocks, I will also make a semantic argument that you do not "benefit" from the dividend at all. A dividend payment is cash out of the door for the company, so the value of the company (and hence the stock) is reduced by the same amount. You'd trading a little bit of your stock value for an equal amount of cash.

It's not like, say, interest on a bond where the interest paid increases your overall value.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of stocks pay dividends quarterly, approximately 3 months apart.  The are a small amount that pay monthly or semi-annually.

There are lots of web sites that will provide dividend information.  [Fidelity](https://screener.fidelity.com/ftgw/etf/snapshot/distributions.jhtml?symbols=SPY) offers historical dividends here.

If you google "Dividend Calendar" you'll find lots of others as well.  Here's the one for the [NASDAQ](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/dividends) and one at [Market Chameleon](https://marketchameleon.com/Calendar/Dividend).

Comment: Siemens actually pays a yearly dividend, which I don't think is that rare

Answer (score 0):

Most stocks pay dividends quarterly (every three months). When "the" ex-dividend date is listed, it is the most recently announced one. The exact date within the month can vary; the next one will be announced when it gets closer.

Comment: So for a stock that pays a dividend quarterly, an ex-dividend date will be announced before each dividend payment ?

Comment: @YassineAlami Yes.

Comment: The company announces the ex-dividend and record dates well before the ex-dividend date,